# What should I do with the extra grounding wire in my ceiling fan box?

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan, grounding-and-bonding

I am installing a Hampton Bay Ceiling Fan that has a transmitter install for the remote.  I have a green ground and a bare copper ground coming from my ceiling box.  I have a green ground coming from the ceiling fan motor.  The instructions say to connect the two green ground wires (the ceiling box ground and the ceiling fan motor ground) with an electric connecter.  I understand that, however, I am not sure what to do with the copper ground wire out of my ceiling box.  Can I curve the top and attach it to the ground screw on the fan mounting bracket? Do I connect it with the other two green ground wires and make it a party of three?  The rest of the instructions are self explanatory but I want to make this install safe.  Need to make sure I have done the right thing with the grounding wires. The fans are fine if I only want the fan motion, however, using this transmitter with the remote would also provide a light option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bare copper wire and any green insulated wires are meant to be connected together, making it a "party of three" as you stated in your question. That said there is another consideration to take into account as well. These safety ground wires are also meant to be connected to a common ground point of the electrical box as well.

If one of these wires (green or bare copper) coming out of your box already attaches to a safety ground point in the box then you have no more to do than the "party of three" connections.

If neither of these two wires are connected to the electrical box safety ground then it will be necessary to add an additional pigtail green or bare copper wire to the box safety ground and join it with the other three making a "party of four" connection.

Comment: Awww, can I connect the bare copper wire to the metal ceiling box ground screw (which is under the fan ceiling bracket) to obtain safety ground, and then connect the two green wires with a connector nut?

Comment: Can you show a picture of how to put the green to the copper wire?